# htmlParse failed to load external entity

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rcurl, httr

I am trying to extract data from

```
url <- ("http://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1647-India")
```

**Code**:

```
library(XML) 
my <- htmlParse(url)
```

> Error: failed to load external entity from url

**Try 2**:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
qw <- GET(url)
my <- readHTMLTable(rawToChar(qw$content))
```

> Error in qw$content : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

**Try 3**:

```
qw <- getURL(url)
my <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

> Error: could not find function "getURL"
>
> Error: failed to load external entity from url

Answer (score 0):

The url gives `301` status, and the cause of that is the website only allows `SSL` connection. Try with this (essentially the difference is using `https` instead of `http`).

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url <- ("https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1647-India")
htmlContent <- getURL(url)
htmlTree <- htmlTreeParse(htmlContent)
```